# How to create a dummy variable for time in a difference in difference analysis in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to do a difference in difference analysis on data from a randomized controlled trial where the control and treatment occurred during the exact same time period. I know that my model should look like: outcome = time + treatment + time*treatment. But I don't know how to formulate the dummy variable for time because the treatment happened at the same time as the control. This is different to traditional DID, where the control and treatment occur in 2 different time periods.

Also, I understand that DID is used as a quasi-experimental approach to simulate randomization when randomization is not feasible, but it is being used in this case to account for baseline differences in the outcome between the control and treatment groups.

I appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  It is entirely unclear to me how an experiment that did not include time as a predictor (even as an uncontrolled term) can be used to make inferences about the effect of time.

Comment: Actually this is a statistical question that should be _migrated_  to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).